# NSUserDefaults sometimes returns wrong value

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I save the user profile picture ID of a user as a string in NSUserDefaults e.g. @"12". When I do that, I call the synchronize method immediately.

When I read this value from NSUserDefaults, it returns @"12" in maybe 99% of the time. But sometimes, it returns a different value (which I cannot find due to the rarity of the event, but suspect it is either nil or some default value (?)).

The code I use to write/read is very simple:

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:@"12" forKey:@"photoID"];
[userDefaults synchronize];

NSString* photoID=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"photoID"];
```

I know the value sometimes returned is incorrect because the app at the time behaves as if the value was different (i.e. user contacts are notified the profile picture has changed).

And when that happens, the next call to objectForKey returns the correct value, so user contacts received another notification the profile picture has changed again.

Comment: I only need to call synchronize when I change default values, which is not that often, so it is not a worry. I doubt removing it would change anything and the problem is it would take days to find out if the error recurs or not. I am hoping to hear from someone who faced a similar issue, i.e. things work fine 99%+ of the time but sometimes don't.

Comment: Not all bugs can be reproduced easily. If I knew about the behavior or circumstances, I would probably be able to fix the bug. And what I am looking for is someone who experienced this very issue. I am willing to experiment but I am pretty sure calling synchronize does not cause the bug.

Comment: I guess you are right... Fair enough.

Comment: i have a feeling the bug does not lie in the code you have shown, but somewhere else, if you put that code in a for loop for a million times it would give you the correct results 100% of the time im fairly certain. behaviour like this is usually the result of threading without correct mutex locks

Comment: You are guessing that the value returned is incorrect, you need to create a test. Print the blue when the error condition occurs.

Comment: Fonix/zaph: Thanks for these suggestions. I will dig in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSSynchronize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) is not guaranteed to succeed and returns a BOOL. 
Note that syncrhonize simply writes the data to disk but NSUserDefaults keeps the data in memory as well. Calling it after every write is probably not needed, though I've done it myself and many examples on the net do that.

From the Apple documentation:

> use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

Disclaimer: speculation
It's possible that the act of failed synchronize is causing objectForKey to fail. The class knows the data it has may be wrong and so returns nil instead. This is more likely if you are calling synchronize successively and excessively or otherwise doing IO intensive operations.

Comment: Many thanks, that sounds very plausible. Although the app does not call synchronize very often (so I am not sure it is due to this), it is quite clear that the get method is failing at rare points of time. I just checked with the user and it appears he indeed made some changes to other settings (thus calling Synchronize) shortly before the event occurred. I guess it was just a case of bad luck. Anyway I will now check in case the get method returns nil, was just curious to understand why and how often this could happen. Apparently it is very rare as I try to reproduce but could not..